# How to use platform's preinstalled ringtone in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, plugins

I wanna use system's preinstalled ringtone and alarm in iOS/Android platform of Cordova.

I used cordova-plugin-native-ringtone, but it's only use preinstalled notification sounds.

How can I get ringtone and alarm list and use?

I should make plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the ringtone or alarm list, you need to call the getRingtones with the 3rd optional parameter (only works for Android).  Here is an example for ringtone:

```
cordova.plugins.NativeRingtones.getRingtone(function(ringtoneList) {
    ringtones = ringtoneList;
},
function(err) {
    alert(err);
}, 'ringtone');
```

If you want the alarm list, pass `'alarm'` instead of `'ringtone'`

Comment: I already tried this option ('alarm' and 'ringtone'). I got same list of notification sounds from "content://media/internal/audio/media/". but I wanna use file://system/media/audio/rigtones(or alarms , notifications)(Android has 3 folders in audio folder.)

Comment: @Hika what device/android version?

Comment: device is huawei p10 lite. version is 7.0.　cordova 8.0, android platform 6.4.0. 3 folders Android has also exist in my device.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in NativeRingtones.java from but I think it's too late

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No this is not the solution.

Comment: The pugin compare with "==" strings to know what param you sent, if alarm or antoher, so it has if and else but always enter it and there is the default value, I replaced "==" with equals